# error: conflicting types for 'GLVID_SetPalette' void GLVID_SetPalette (unsigned char *palette)

Tags: c, macos, gcc

I basically know next to nothing about programming but have tried to learn a few things since I'm interested in source codes for various games, so here's some source code I grabbed online and tried to compile for Mac OS X, but I get this error:

```
/Users/coffeegator/fteqw-code/engine/gl/gl_vidmacos.c:116:6: error: conflicting
  types for 'GLVID_SetPalette'
```

void GLVID_SetPalette (unsigned char *palette)

So I looked at the section referred to in gl_vidmacos.c and found this:

```
GLVID_SetPalette(palette);

return true;
}

void GLVID_DeInit(void)
{
killCocoa();
}

void GLVID_SetPalette (unsigned char *palette)
{
qbyte *pal;
unsigned int r,g,b;
int i;
unsigned *table1;
extern qbyte gammatable[256];
```

(Sorry if it's not copy pasted well, I'm new to this)

I know it has something to do with declarations and definitions but I can't figure out what I'm supposed to change in this code to make the compilation work. If anyone can help me out I'd appreciate it.

Once again, I'm new to this so sorry if I've asked this question poorly or left out any important bits of code, but I've done the best I can. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to tell, since most of the code is missing... but this could be happening because `GLVID_SetPalette()` was not declared before it was called.  Depending on how you're compiling, this can cause a declaration to be automatically generated which will return `int`, which conflicts with the `void` return type of the actual function.  Solution: declare functions before you use them.

Comment: Looking at [`gl_vidmacos.c`](https://github.com/ProfessorKaos64/fte-quake/blob/048c96725978fdbc5cbc3b51cfc973ca222450b5/engine/gl/gl_vidmacos.c), adding following declaration at the top of the file could help: `void GLVID_SetPalette (unsigned char *palette);`

Comment: That seems to do the trick, thanks. I seem to be getting an unrelated error, though.